# Does covering a mattress with sheets prevent dust mites and their allergens?

Tags: health-and-safety

Does covering a mattress with sheets prevent dust mites and their allergens?

Comment: Please clarify, what exactly is your question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, normal sheets(no matter the thread count)  will not keep dust mites and pollen from entering your mattress and box spring. It is possible a mattress can increase it's weight due to these two processes.

So I will assume this question to mean HOW can you cover the mattress to prevent.......

Well, for one I never take the mattress out of its original bag. It's air proof, so that covers everything else, plus it's free. I believe what you want is a [vinyl plastic mattress cover](http://www.bedbathstore.com/vinzipmatcov.html). It will keep out EVERYTHING, so you're set. However any pre-existing mite colonies in the mattress will continue to eat the dust in the mattress until they die... however once you put it on, you will be separated from them hence forth.

Comment: There's [some dispute](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2545/does-a-mattress-double-its-weight-due-to-dust-mites-and-their-debris) over that weight tripling claim.  But mattress covers and general hygiene are your best defense, IMO.

Comment: I liked the cover idea! I need to check if it exist in my country. Now, about using the original bag, if you mean the plastic bag, I've read it's not good to use it, but I don't know why.

Comment: @Niall I will edit the claim, however relating to your comment, yes as I stated in the answer, plastic covers are the best way to prevent infestation, but simply, it's the skin that they feed off. So no level of hygene will keep you from losing dead skin, however the cleaner you are, the cleaner your bed will be, to an extent.

Comment: @Tom In response to the country difference I will say this. In America the plastic covering that comes with most mattresses is water proof, light, and durable. It is identical to a vinal cover except the original bag is clear.

Comment: I bought mine from this place and am very happy.  I have suffered from dust mite allergies for years.  Sheets don't do anything.

Comment: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/4977/155